# Phonegap app translation

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, localization, translation

I have a working Phonegap app which is currently in danish, but i need to translate it to several other languages.

I have never worked with localization before, but the concept seems pretty straight-forward.

I found a localization-library ([http://www.localeplanet.com/index.html][1])

In the HOWTO-section on the site there are some examples like the one below:

```
alert(_('Hello, world!'));
```

So if i have an alert box like this

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    'Logging in',
    function () { },
    'Your user has been created',
    'Ok'
);
```

I simply translate it like so:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
    _('Logging in'),
    function () { },
    _('Your user has been created'),
    _('Ok')
);
```

But what about "hardcoded" text? For example I have a lot of buttons like this:

```
<button>Continue job</button>    
<button>Cancel job</button>    
<button>Go back</button>
```

Do i have to give each and every button in my app an ID and the set the text with, for example, $.text()?

EDIT:
im looking for something like this

```
<?=$var?>
```

but in regular html not php

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function to take all 'button's and replace the current text with translated text.

```
$.("button").each(function (){
    translateText($(this).text(), $(this));
});
```